# What are the criteria used to represent Stack Exchange sites on the sites page? (Grid view)

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

I noticed that [the sites' page on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) has been changed, and by default sites are shown by balloons.

[image: screenshot]

What is not clear to me is why some sites are shown with a bigger balloon than other sites. For example, *WordPress Answers* has less questions, answers and users than *Programmers*, but its balloon is bigger.

What are the criteria used to show the sites on that page?

Comment: In one of the earlier SE podcasts, Joel mentioned the amusing fact that when Christianity came out of beta it pushed all the scientific SE's off of the "main" page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The sites are ordered by creation date, but then shifted around a bit (by the [jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin) so they all fit tightly in the container despite being different sizes.

The site *sizes* are subject to change, but hard-coded for now, and loosely based on a combination of factors, including site traffic, whether we want to "feature" a particular site, Jin's whims, etc.

Comment: I am glad unicorns are not involved, for once.

Comment: *What?!* No unicorns?

Answer (score 6):

From a [conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3612132#3612132) in the SF Comms room

> the dev tells me that the site order is roughly based on the site's age, though there is some other fuzzy logic involved.

and [later](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3612209#3612209) in reply to the above

> tis true. I've seen the code. public List getFrontPageOrder() { return fuzzificate(sites.OrderBy(s => s.Traffic)); }

Comment: `fuzzificate` ...really? Must be pre-code review

Comment: Yeah, that Java style camel casing would have gotten someone fired.  We're a Pascal casing shop.

Answer (score -4):

It seems to be that it is based on [**traffic**](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic).

If you look at that link, all of the sites with **bigger** bubbles are the highest on the list.

Comment: Although, now that I look at it, this *might* **not** be the case.

Comment: It's not traffic, as Wordpress is larger than Programmers (say).