# The Legend of the stackexchange.com/sites grid view

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

The [stackexchange sites view](https://stackexchange.com/sites) represents the set of sites via an intriguing arrangement of squares of varying size and color when using the default "grid" view.  But a legend for the layout has not been found.

### ![enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw3tj.png

A previous question here ([What are the criteria used to represent Stack Exchange sites on the sites page? (Grid view)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123997/155203)) established that the order is determined by the site creation date, shifted by the [jQuery isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) as needed for the layout.  It also clarifies that the sizes are hard-coded based on some officially "fuzzy" relationship to site traffic and "Jin's whims".  Assuming this is a misspelling of Jinn / Djinn / Genie, I take this to be confirmation that magic is involved :)

It prompts this follow-up question:

- What determines the color of site boxes?
- When did the grid view make its debut?
- When will the legend be revealed in its proper place, for all to see?

*Thanks to @BenLee for supplying the image that my title yearned for :)*

Comment: It's likely an existing plugin, like http://masonry.desandro.com/ or http://masonjs.com/

Comment: Correction: this is what they're using http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

Comment: This is totally how I interpreted the question title at first: http://weknowmemes.com/generator/uploads/generated/g1379803969676281257.jpg

Comment: The image in the question is a Link, yet, not click-able...! (Sorry)

Comment: Almost feeling sorry for finding a dupe to this!

Comment: Is it really a dupe though? This question asks about the technical solution used; the other, about the criteria used for sorting

Comment: Thanks!  But the color code (a major part of the legend) has not yet been revealed.  I've edited it to incorporate the info from the previous question and clarify what remains open.  Please vote to reopen.

Comment: It's very likely that Jin (the designer for Stack Exchange) just manually chooses a color for each site. It's probably not generated in any way.